# Is there a way to make a button print content from page and then submit(post) to backend JS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, bootstrap-4

I need to firstly print content from page, and then submit to perform some backed database change using contents from form post, is there a way to do both using a single button?

I've tried putting the print in on click function but it won't post after print

HTML:

```
<div class="printable" id="printableArea" style="display:block;">
    <div class="card" style="width: 500px;">
            ...
    </div>
</div>

<button id="printBtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary print-visibility-hide" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">Print</button>
```

JS:

```
<script>
  function printDiv(divName) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    var count = $("#count").val();

    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

    for(var i=1; i<count; i++){
        document.body.innerHTML += printContents;
    }

    window.print();

    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
  }

<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onafterprint = function(){
   console.log("Printing completed...");
}
```

or just add after `window.print();`

```
setTimeout(() => { ...callback here }, 100);
```